# Turning any number into currency-C#

Tags: c#, currency

I was wondering if there was any way to turn any number into currency. For example, the user inputs 23.7264 and the output is $23.74. I know I could probably turn the number into a string, evaluate for a decimal point, and round but I am looking for a way that doesn't convert the number to a string.

Comment: Where is the input coming from? Where is it going to?
Do you have some code to show what you have tried?

Comment: I assume you actually meant the output should be $23.73?

Comment: [MSDN String.format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @Josh those are conversion fees